# Python: data = s.recv(1024) socket.timeout: timed out

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, chat

I am trying to create a simple chat room app where multiple clients can talk to everyone and all their messages can be seen by everyone else connected to the server.

However I keep getting a socket time out error.

When trying with telnet as the client like so `telnet 127.0.0.1 2066` , the application works fine, however once I add my own `client.py` that's when the issues arise

To run the `server.py` you can do `python3 server.py`

My `server.py` looks like so:

```
import socket
import configparser
from _thread import * 
import sys

num_threads=0

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

HOST = config['details']['HOST']
PORT= int(config['details']['PORT'])

server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))

print("Server started at "+ HOST +":" + str(PORT))

clients=[]

server_socket.listen(10)



def client_thread(client_socket):
    global num_threads
    num_threads+=1
    print("Encrat Chat Room\n".encode())

    while True:
        try:    
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)
            #reply = data.decode()
            if not data:
                break

            for client in clients:
                if client  != client_socket:
                     client.send(data)          
         except:
            continue
    client_socket.close()



while True:
    client_socket , address = server_socket.accept()
    clients.append(client_socket)
    print("User (%s, %s) connected\n" % address)
    start_new_thread(client_thread, (client_socket, ))


    while num_threads > 0:
        pass





server_socket.close()
```

To run the `client.py` you can do: `python3 client.py 127.0.0.1 2066 your_name`

My `client.py` looks like so:

```
import socket
import sys, select



if (len(sys.argv) < 4):
    print("Usage: python client.py <hostname> <port> <name> ")
    sys.exit()



 HOST=sys.argv[1]
 PORT=int(sys.argv[2])
 NAME=sys.argv[3]


 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 s.settimeout(3)


 s.connect((HOST, PORT))


 print("Connection established with server\n")
 sys.stdout.write("\n[Me :]")


 while True:

     data = s.recv(1024) #timeout error here

     if data:   
         print(data.decode())

     else:

        message =sys.stdin.readline()
        message ='[' + NAME + ':] ' + message

         s.send(message.encode())

         sys.stdout.write("\n[Me :] " )
         sys.stdout.flush();
```

My `config.ini` looks like so:

```
[details]

HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=2066
```

A better way to write the `client.py` would also be appreciated. Most examples I've come cross only allow one client to communicate. I want all clients to communicate with each other like a group chat

Thanks in advance

Comment: Client talk first, server haven't any idea which user want this response...

Comment: I thought that's what my loop did in server.py. Every user gets the response

Comment: Broadcasting method haven't any client. if you need some client answer redirect to another one socket.

Comment: But if i was to `print(len(clients)) ` and I had 2 clients connected, it does say hat the size of the clients array is 2 ...

Comment: Yes `connected not include any message!`. You ready for learn but we not talking any information.

Comment: Are you talking about my `client.py` or my `server.py` ?

Comment: Client talk first !if you want bidirectional communication..

Comment: Yeah but my `server.py` works fine with `telnet` even when more than 1 person connects to the server ..

Comment: Telnet send some data after connected ! Not only connect !

Answer (score -1):

import socket
class MyNet:
@staticmethod
def conn(z):
s=socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET,type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
message="xx"
s.sendto(message.encode(),z)
d,s = s.recvfrom(1024)
print(s(1))
return d
class A(MyNet):
pass
b=A

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).